# Should we republish the app after changing the domain of app-ads.txt?

Tags: android, ios, admob, release, app-ads.txt

We have released some apps on both App Store and Play Store. They support AdMob and work perfectly. Recently, we decided to replace the website domain and passed the app-ads.txt to the new one.

Will the ads still work? Do I need to change any information in both store, rebuild the apps and publish again a new version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** You need to release an update for your **iOS app**, to change marketing URL which is the one AdMob check for app-ads.txt on.

on **Android** you do not need to release new version, but you must go to store listing settings from Google Play Console to change app's website.

then after both changes are published to app store and Google play, it may take 24 hour for AdMob crawlers to verify the change.

Comment: Didn't knew that a build is required to update marketing url on itunes. Also maketing url is an optional field. I wonder why they have this policy ? Hope they change it in future

Comment: Yes, unfortunately Apple need a new build for everything instead of promotional text which is so frustrating. I think they have this policy because unlike Google they need to review every change by humans, so if they open the door for easy changes the review time of apps will skyrocket.

Answer (score -1):

Edit - New Build required only for **iTunes**. Hope they change this policy!.

Apps are not required to be rebuild since only domain name is changed.

You need to make sure new developer website is updated on Play Stores ( apple and android ) and then update apps-ads.txt. It takes upto 24 hours to reverify the changes on admob side.

Check status of your apps-ads.txt on admob website https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9788846

Use this links to resolved any issues listed above https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9776740